# Centrar LinearLayout en la pantalla del dispositivo

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, alertdialog, linearlayout

Estoy tratando de centrar un AlertDialog estructurado con un LinearLayout. Básicamente estoy validando un parámetro para cambiar su tamaño ya que internamente tiene un tamaño predefinido.

La opción mas viable es hacerlo directamente en el archivo .xml poniendo la propiedad *android:layout_height="wrap_content"* pero en este caso solo requieren cambiar su tamaño solo si el parámetro recibe un valor verdadero.

Desde el onCreate llamo así:

```
public static Dialog mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.btn_normal).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mDialog = alertDialog("Este dialogo es comun", R.layout.alert_dialog, true, false);
        mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_aceptar).setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        });
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btn_param).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mDialog = alertDialog("Este dialogo es parametrizado y esta capacitado para transponer mas de una linea de texto en su informacion. " +
                "Mientras tanto esta funcionando como una demo para una aplicacion de prueba.", R.layout.alert_dialog, true, true);
        mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_aceptar).setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        });
    });
}
```

Y el método que me recibe los parámetros es este:

```
private Dialog alertDialog(String msg, int resID, boolean cancelable, boolean ajustable) {
    final Dialog pd = new Dialog(this, R.style.AlertDialog_AppCompat);
    pd.setContentView(resID);
    pd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    TextView txt_info = pd.findViewById(R.id.txt_info);
    LinearLayout container_linear = pd.findViewById(R.id.container_linear);
    txt_info.setText(msg);
    pd.setCancelable(cancelable);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(cancelable);

    if (ajustable) {
        container_linear.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(700, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        container_linear.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL));
    }

    pd.create();
    pd.show();
    return pd;
}
```

He intentado otra opcion y ninguna ha funcionado:

```
container_linear.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0));
```

El tamaño ya lo he logrado controlar, solo me falta centrarlo en la pantalla del dispositivo.

Answer (score 1):

Si el dialog que piensas mostrar posee un contenedor padre, lo que puedes hacer es bindearlo y darle la propiedad de `Gravity.CENTER` cuando necesites centrarlo, debes tener en cuenta que esta propiedad lo que hace en este caso es centrar los elementos dentro del contenedor, mas no el contenedor.

En tu caso decidiste usar las siguientes lineas para centrar:

```
 container_linear.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL));
```

En su lugar, como mencione anteriormente, podrías reemplazarlo por lo siguiente:

Bindeamos el contenedor padre donde esta el container_linear:

```
 LinearLayout container_padre = pd.findViewById(R.id.container_padre);
```

Y a ese container le damos la propiedad de `Gravity.CENTER` para centrar los elementos en su interior:

```
container_padre.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Con esto tendríamos centrado el elemento deseado, es decir el container_linear.

PD: Esta validación asignada, para que puedas aplicarlo de manera correcta en tu prueba, debería ir insertada dentro de la condición `if(ajustable){}`